# Error retrieving dataset with Informix function on .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, informix

I'm having  problems retrieving the result of a function that's on Informix and called from a VB .NET code.

This is the Stack Trace:

```
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDateTime.ValidateRange()
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.internalGetIfxDateTime(Int32 i)
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.GetValue(Int32 column, TypeMap typeMap)
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at IBM.Data.Informix.IfxDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)
   at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
   at ServicesDAL.Repositories.RepositorioBase.GetDatatableFromCommand(String connectionString, String commandText, List`1 parameters, CommandType commandType, String& errorMessage)
```

Any clue why is this happening?

And when I execute the function from the sql client everything works fine and all the results are displayed.

And this is the code:

```
internal static DataTable GetDatatableFromCommand(string connectionString, string commandText, List<ParameterObject> parameters, CommandType commandType, ref string errorMessage)
        {

            DataTable dt = null;
            errorMessage = null;
            IfxConnection connection = null;
            try
            {
                // Conecto con la base de datos
                connection = ConnectToDatabase(connectionString, ref errorMessage);

                // Si es distinto de null y no hay errores entonces se conecto correctamente
                if (connection != null && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorMessage))
                {
                    IfxCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = commandText;
                    cmd.CommandType = commandType;

                    if (parameters != null)
                    {
                        IfxParameter parameter = null;
                        foreach (ParameterObject parObj in parameters)
                        {
                            parameter = new IfxParameter(parObj.Orden, parObj.Tipo);
                            parameter.Value = parObj.Valor;
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                        }
                    }

                    // Antes de ejecutar la llamada a la base de datos cambio el currentculture
                    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");

                    // Creo un adaptador que le paso el comando y ya el lo parsea con el dataTable
                    IfxDataAdapter dataAdapter = new IfxDataAdapter(cmd);
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                errorMessage = ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cierro la conexion siempre despues de sacar los datos
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    connection = null;
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Update: Could I format the date **before** it reaches the .net program? I mean, format the date in the informix function.

Comment: Post your code and the full exception, not just parts of the stack trace. This doesn't seem like any attempt to call an Informix function but an attempt to read a *DateTime* value. If your code expects a datetime but the database contains a *string*, you'll get an error.  You didn't include the actual exception though

Comment: The issue is obviusly the data that the DB is returning.

Comment: I mean, this same procedure sometimes work and others not. The difference between the cases is the data.

Comment: The issue is using the *wrong data type* in the database. Informix has date types, just like other databases. If a date is stored as *text* instead, there's no way to tell what it means. It could be in any local format, or even multiple formats. What is the table's schema? What is the type of the columns that hold the dates?

Comment: If the fields are string types, by trying to read them as dates you ask the database to  parse them. `25/12/2018` will be parsed correctly in most countries and fail in the US. `4/7/2018` will succeed everywhere but return *different* dates. Best case, you are trying to read those strings using a different locale. You could read them as strings and parse them with `DateTime.Parse(value,CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(thatCulture))`. Worst case, the fields contain mixed formats in which case you can't be certain what any value is

Comment: Assuming all text is in the same format, you could set the [locale properties](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.netpr.doc/ids_net_065.htm) of the `IfxConnection` object to force it to use the locale you want for parsing. The *real* solution would be to fix the table type, but Informix is only used in rather ... old installations, so I suspect a) it's impossible to fix the problem and b) someone would have run into problems in the past 30 years.

Comment: Well, the column data types are datetime [Year to Second], which means, if I'm not wrong,that the data is stored as datetime, not string. That's the most confusing part. Everything looks fine, but it just fails at the point when is trying to populate the datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're filling a blank DataTable, this is a bug or limitation in the informix ADO.NET provider.  So you'll need to work around this in exactly the way you suggest:

> Could I format the date before it reaches the .net program? I mean, format the date in the informix function.

Yes.  Write a query using Informix SQL that invokes the function converts the data types to something that the ADO.NET provider can handle.  Strings are the fallback here, and you can convert them to .NET types yourself later.